# Batch pull a variable from a random line in a text file, then another variable based on that number

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch file which selects a variable from one text file via choosing a random line, then sets the entire line as a variable. Then it sets a second variable using the same line number previously generated to select the first variable to set a second variable from a second text file. Example: If the batch file randomly selects the 4th line of `test1.txt` as a variable, it will then select the 4th line of `test2.txt` as the variable.

The variables from the two text files are related, and I can't think of a way to get a batch file to read one line of a text file and get two variables out of it. (Especially not when one will be a text string and the other will be a number.)

I found this code which can randomly pull a line from a text file then store it as a variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set INPUT_FILE="test1.txt"

:: # Count the number of lines in the text file and generate a random number
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`find /V /C "" ^< %INPUT_FILE%`) do set lines=%%a
set /a randnum=%RANDOM% * lines / 32768 + 1, skiplines=randnum-1

:: # Extract the line from the file
set skip=
if %skiplines% gtr 0 set skip=skip=%skiplines%
for /f "usebackq %skip% delims=" %%a in (%INPUT_FILE%) do set "randline=%%a" 
set line=!randline!
```

If this is run, it will return the entire string existing at the randomly chosen line from within `test1.txt`. But I can't for the life of me find a way to store the variable %skiplines%, and then use that to pull another variable from `test2.txt`.

I have tried several things. Most notably:

```
set /a "line = 0"
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in (test2.txt) do (
set /a "line = line + 1"
if !line!==%skiplines% set thing=%%a
```

When this is run, the batch file processing exits instantly, or if it gets to the output it will say `Echo is off` instead of the output that should come from `test2.txt`. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correct your example code, you'd need

```
for /f "usebackq %skip% delims=" %%a in (%INPUT_FILE%) do set "randline=%%a"&GOTO FOUNDLINE1
:FOUNDLINE1
set line=%randline%
```

Although *why* you'd want to set `line` when the dta you evidently want is in `randline` is a mystery to me. I'd use

```
for /f "usebackq %skip% delims=" %%a in (%INPUT_FILE%) do set "line=%%a"&GOTO FOUNDLINE1
:FOUNDLINE1
```

And to select the same line number from the second file, the code would be

```
for /f "usebackq %skip% delims=" %%a in (%INPUT_FILE2%) do set "line2=%%a"&GOTO FOUNDLINE2
:FOUNDLINE2
```

But since you've given no indication of the contents of the files or what you actully want given the file contents, anything more is speculation.

You haven't shown the closing parenthesis in the second codefrag. Batch will object and terminate if that is missing.

Comment: The rules say I should make the most relevant to everyone. I thought detailing what exactly I'm doing would violate that. I'm making a random generator to create a shop inventory for tabletop RPGs.

test1 is full of item names, one per line. test 2 is full of numbers indicating the item's basic cost in gold pieces. The randomly chosen item must always be paired with the correct base price so the specific price at the shop generated is calculated correctly.

Comment: @Meep, why wouldn't you just create a single file with key pairs?

Comment: Rules, schmules. They're trying to communicate that we need an idea of the data you are dealing with and the method you're using in order to achieve some result but avoiding armchair-lawyerdom and war-and-peace in the law-library. What we *don't* want is a 200-line routine where half-a-dozen lines is relevant. Hence, a few lines from each of your files edited into your question, with an illustration of what you would want to derive from your data (an how, if that's not totally obvious) is useful in fixing your code or formulating an alternative approach.

Comment: @MeeptheChangeling, Compo makes a great point.  You are over complicating the solution to your problem. A simple delimited file with the item names in column 1 and the cost in column 2 would be the easiest solution.

Comment: @Compo I'm doing this only way I know how to do it. I would love to know how to do it with one text file.

Comment: Well, you've been asked to edit samples of your data into your question. If you do that, then we may be able to concoct a solution.